# Problems with file download

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qwebkit

I have this QT script using webkit. I can download files no problem but I can't get the progress bar moving in the file dialog. I think the network reply has already been sent before I call the progress dialog as there is a delay from clicking the download link and then then `qDebug() << "Left click - download!";`  being echo's out into console. How can I intercept the netwrok reply before it has  finished and the unsupportedContent() method is called?

**EDIT:**
I could strip it out and use `reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));` but I don't actually know the URL it could be any link the user clicks, there is no predefined URL?

```
void MainWindow::unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply *reply) {

    qDebug() << "Left click - download!";
    qDebug() << "Bytes to download: " << reply->bytesAvailable();

    QString str = reply->rawHeader("Content-Disposition");

    QString end = str.mid(21);
    end.chop(1);

    qDebug() << "File name: " << end;
    qDebug() << "File type: " << reply->rawHeader("Content-Type");
    qDebug() << "File size (bytes): " << reply->bytesAvailable();
    QString defaultFileName = QFileInfo(end).fileName();
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"), defaultFileName);
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;

    file = new QFile(fileName);
    if(!file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Downloader",
            tr("Unable to save the file %1: %2.")
            .arg(fileName).arg(file->errorString()));
        delete file;
        file = NULL;
        return;
    }

    downloadRequestAborted = false;

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(downloadFinished()));
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(downloadReadyRead()));
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
        connect(progressDialog, SIGNAL(canceled()), this, SLOT(cancelDownload()));
        progressDialog->setLabelText(tr("Downloading %1...").arg(fileName));
        //downloadButton->setEnabled(false);
        progressDialog->exec();


    //QFile file(fileName);
    //file.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly );
    //file.write(reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable()));
    //file.close();
}

void MainWindow::downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    qDebug() << bytesReceived << bytesTotal;
    if(downloadRequestAborted)
        return;
    progressDialog->setMaximum(bytesTotal);
    progressDialog->setValue(bytesReceived);
}

void MainWindow::downloadReadyRead()
{
    if(file)
        file->write(reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable()));
}

void MainWindow::downloadFinished()
{
    qDebug() << "Download finished!";
    if(downloadRequestAborted)
    {
        if(file)
        {
            file->close();
            file->remove();
            delete file;
            file = NULL;
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
        progressDialog->hide();
        //downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
        return;
    }

    downloadReadyRead();
    progressDialog->hide();
    //downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
    file->flush();
    file->close();

    if(reply->error())
    {
        //Download failed
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Download failed", tr("Failed: %1").arg(reply->errorString()));
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
    reply = NULL;
    delete file;
    file = NULL;
}

void MainWindow::cancelDownload()
{
    downloadRequestAborted = true;
    reply->abort();
    progressDialog->hide();
    //downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's possible attempting to access a header, or get the bytesAvailable, is causing the reply to be downloaded in full... I'd recommend you try stripping everything that isn't necessary to display progress and see if it changes the behavior any. P.S. console output can be kind of tricky due to buffering, although that does not necessarily mean much.

Comment: Thanks @JohnChadwick I will try it quickly. Though the reply has already finished in my unsupportedContent() method. I could strip it out and use `reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));` but I don't actually know the URL it could be any link the user clicks, there is no predefined URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above method was working the whole time the problem was the bytes it was receiving was so small you could not tell it had downloaded at all, once I attempted to download a larger file the bytes being downloaded were adequately displayed :)

Here is the method I ended up with that could receive a request and save it disk.

```
void MainWindow::unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply *reply) {

    QString str = reply->rawHeader("Content-Disposition");

    QString end = str.mid(21);
    end.chop(1);

    QString defaultFileName = QFileInfo(end).fileName();
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"), defaultFileName);
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;

    file = new QFile(fileName);
    if(!file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Downloader",
            tr("Unable to save the file %1: %2.")
            .arg(fileName).arg(file->errorString()));
        delete file;
        file = NULL;
        return;
    }

    downloadRequestAborted = false;
    if(!reply->isFinished()){
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));

    connect(progressDialog, SIGNAL(canceled()), SLOT(cancelDownload()));
    progressDialog->setLabelText(tr("Downloading %1...").arg(fileName));
    progressDialog->exec();
    //return;
    }

    if(downloadRequestAborted)
    {
        if(file)
        {
            file->close();
            file->remove();
            delete file;
            file = NULL;
        }
        reply->abort();
        reply->deleteLater();
        progressDialog->hide();
        return;
    }

    file->write(reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable()));
    file->flush();
    file->close();
    file = NULL;

    if(file == NULL){
        isDownload = true;
        fileURL = fileName;
    systray->showMessage("CytoViewer v1.0", "Download finished - Click to open", QSystemTrayIcon::NoIcon, 10000);
    }
}
```